# Visual Studio 2022 font size is way too small in the tooltips. How to increase that font size?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Recently in my installation of VS2022 the tooltip message font size went microscopic as shown in the clip below.
I've gone thru the font size options in the menus but haven't been able to find anything that will change the size.
Any ideas how to get that back to a readable size?

[image]

Comment: Weird. Since this is super specific, try submitting feedback directly to MS via the "Send Feedback" button in the upper right of the window.

Comment: @Casey this isn't really that specific.  It should be a simple settings change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Tools → Options → Environment → Fonts and Colors and change the drop down to "Editor Tooltip" and then change the "Size" drop down value (the default is 9, yours appears to be set to something like 6):

[image: fonts and colors windows showing font size control]

Comment: That didn't change anything unfortuantely

Comment: @johnS I would try checking your display settings then and see if scaling is making this happen. But when I change this setting in my answer to 6, the tool tips look identical to your screenshot. Have you also tried reinstalling visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

The cause was an extension that extended the intellisense functionality. The resolution was to remove the suspect extension, restart VS2022, then reinstall the extension.

The errant extension was either CodeRush or CodeMaid.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Option" panel go to "Fonts and Colors" and press the button "Use Defaults".
Then custom your text size using Ctrl +, Ctrl - or Ctrl Mouse Scroll
[image]