# How to prevent tooltip from scaling with text editor zoom?

Tags: tooltip, visual-studio-2022, font-size

Hello I updated to the 17.7.6 version of VS 2022 Community edition and the noticed that tooltip size decreased. I realized that the tooltip window and font size is now scaling together with text editor size. When it is set to 100% it is usual but I work with 81% setting and sometimes I need to alter it and this tooltip behavior driving me nuts. It happened to me several months ago after an update and since I could not find solution then I reverted the update.
But this issue is still present  and the question is that is there any solution to make their scaling independent like in older version.

I tried to change the font and I know I can offset the font in the Option -> Environment but it still keeps changing if I change the scale of text editor

Big size:

[image: big size]

Small size:

[image: small size]

Comment: Did you take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75187127/7450780)?

Comment: Yes, Iooked there but the solutions dont help. I can offset the tooltip size by changing the font in the options. But it still keeps changin if I change the scale of text editor. And I dont have any extensions installed. My wish is to make them separate so the tooltip window remains unchanged.

Comment: Its not clear what scaling you are changing when you mentioned "100%" and "81%".  What about your Windows scaling like I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187127/visual-studio-2022-font-size-is-way-too-small-in-the-tooltips-how-to-increase-t#comment132942823_75204913) on the previously linked post?  Have you tried to check/change that?

Comment: @TimothyG. There is a dropdown list setting in the bottom of text editor window, near the error and warning icons, you can chose predefined values like 50% 75% etc or input custom one. When you do it the font get larger or smaller but before the tooltip window, as well as intellisense suggestions window were unaffected by this.

Comment: @TimothyG. I linked screenshots the first is with overall scale 158% the second is with 61%. The intellisence suggestions and tooltip window are resized accordinly was not so before. I avoided to update for several months. so cannot say when it first started

Comment: I see what you mean now.  Yea unfortunately I don't think that can be changed. I was running 17.6.4 and this behavior was also present (just updated a few minutes ago to 17.6.6).

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio 2022 Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) has a settings called "Scale Editor Popups" which can be turned on or off:

[image: setting screenshot]